# Convert array element as concatenated string to double in C#

Tags: c#

I'm (very) new to C#; I'm sure the solution here is simple but I can't figure it out.

Suppose I have a simple array of temperatures for Friday.  I receive an abbreviation for the day and an hour (integer) from somewhere and I want to use it to print an element from the array:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] Friday = {54.5, 61.0, 63.5, 58.0};
        string Today = "Fri";
        int Hour = 1;
        double parsed = Convert.ToDouble(Today + "day[" + int + "]");
        Console.WriteLine(parsed);
    }
}
```

Given these conditions, how do I output 61.0?  Then end result should be equivalent to Console.WriteLine(Friday[1]);

Comment: What is the expected output? please be specific. Why did you put day[1] between qoutes?

Comment: Hi..please be specific about the question? Why do you want to convert the string as Today to a double?

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding.  I rewrote my question as well as some of the code.  The main thing is: formatting my concatenated string in such a way that it can return the array element.

Comment: I think what you are trying to accomplish is using `Convert.ToDouble()` in the same way as Javascripts `Eval()`. There is no equivalent for `Eval` in the c# language, nothing will simply take a string and interpret it as code. If you tell us some more information about what your ultimate goal is, we can find an alternative approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really wanted to achieve that I would use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, double[]> dayToValues =
  new Dictionary<string, double[]>
  {
    {"Monday", new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0} },
    {"Friday", new double[] {4.0, 5.0, 6.0} }
  };

string today = "Fri";
int hour = 0;
double firstHourValue = dayToValues[today + "day"][hour];
Console.WriteLine(firstHourValue); // prints "4"
```

If you really need to dynamically build the name of a variable and access it, you have to use reflection. Something like:

```
string fieldName = today.ToLower() + "day";
double[] todays = GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this) as double[];
Console.WriteLine(todays[1]);  // prints "8"
```

This assumes that your have a private field in the current class:

```
double[] friday = { 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 };
```

Of course the reflection code depends on the exact location and scope of the variables. And obvioulsy you would need some null reference checks to use it in the real world. Anyway, using reflection looks quite irrelevant for what seem to be your needs. Use it only if you really have to.

Comment: All responses I've seen so far have been helpful, however I think the dictionary approach is best given the particulars of the objective.  Thank you much Patrice!

Answer (score 1):

c# uses zero-relative indexing.  This means that the 1st element in the array has an index of zero.  So you most likely mean `Friday[0]`.

c# also has the `ToString` method on all objects.  This returns a "human readable"  representation of the object.  So you can do

```
 Console.WriteLine(Friday[0].ToString());
```

Also, `WriteLine` will auto-magically convert any object passed to it into its string repsentation.  So this will also work

```
 Console.WriteLine(Friday[0]);
```

If you want text and a value, then use a Format string, as in

```
 Console.WriteLine("Friday {0}", Friday[0]);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more details on format strings.

Comment: IMO you have misunderstood the OP's question. He wants that  `Console.WriteLine("Fri" + "day[1]")` statement to print 61.0.

Comment: I have taken my downvote. But the answer is not solving the OP's problem neither. In your answer you have not used `today` variable. He wants to convert string to C# code. `Console.WriteLine(today+"day[1]")` =>`Console.WriteLine(Friday[1])`

Comment: I rewrote my question to be more clear . . . Farhad, you are correct, I want it to output as if I was passing Friday[1] directly.